# Vue 2 Axios redirection

Tags: vuejs2, axios

I am making a put request in my Vue/Laravel app to update an entity. The issue I have is that upon doing a `PUT` request app automatically calls another request which I didn't initiate and can't find the source of the trigger:

```
  submit () {
    axios.defaults.headers.put['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
    axios.defaults.headers.put['Accept'] = 'application/json';

    axios.put(this.postMomentUrl, JSON.stringify(this.form))
      .then(response => {
        window.location.href = location.origin + '/task/' + this.form.task_id;
      })
      .catch(error => {console.log('New Task creation: ' + error)})
  },
```

after the initial `PUT` request, program automatically calls another `PUT` request on whatever is stored in `window.location.href`?

Comment: you may need to provide some more info. On this information alone it is hard to tell what else is going on. I can see, though, that you have a redirect there on `.then`, which may be related.

Comment: Where is redirect in `.then`? Isn't response just shorthand for `function(response)`?

Comment: to the best of my knowledge, `window.location.href = ...` is a redirection